# FB comments merged with my website´s comments

Tags: facebook, merge, comments, integration, posting

At the moment my website has its own comments in articles. I decided to merge it with FB comments but of course I don´t want to lose my old comments.

1. Is there a way to merge my old comments with those in FB social plugin? That means: can I somehow insert my old comments in FB Comments plugin?
2. In general, how would you solve this problem? What way of integration would you choose?